# currentdate between not working in php query

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table with columns `section`, `is_date_based` (Yes/No values), `date_start`, `date_end` and `showhide`

query is

```
$query = "select * from tabele where section='Festival Wish' and ((is_date_based='No') OR (is_date_based='Yes' and (CURDATE() between date_start and date_end ))) and showhide='0' order by sort_order asc";
```

**condition 1.** **:** Now if `is_date_based='No'` and `showhide='0'`, row should be displayed...And IT IS WORKING....

**condition 2. :** But if `id_date_based='Yes'` and if `current date-time` is `between date_start and date_end` and `showhide='0'` , ***then and then only*** row should be displayed...

........

but unfortunately, **condition 2** is not working even with required values and data in mysql table...

mysql table structure is

```
section       is_date_based  showhide    date_start          date_end
Festival Wish   Yes            0       2018-09-01 05:00:00  2018-09-05 11:30:00
Festival Wish   No             0       0000-00-00 00:00:00  0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Here second record is shown, properly with above query, but first record is not shown even when current date is between date_start and date_end...

Comment: Please post the output of the following MySQL statement: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tabele`

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. ..and which data type are      date_start and date_end ? .  they dare datetime or varchar ??

Comment: @AlexShesterov sample table structure is added in edited question..please go through question again..

Comment: @scaisEdge sample table structure is added in edited question..please go through question again..

Comment: the date_start and date_end are datetime or varchar ??

Comment: @scaisEdge date_start and date_end are datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need  now() and not curdate(.

`curdate()` return date eg 2018-09-01  `now()` return date an time  2018-09-05 20:34:00 ..

could be also you need  time adjiust for your sample  the 11:30 is past

```
$query = "select * 
        from tabele 
        where section='Festival Wish' 
        and ( (is_date_based='No') 
              OR (is_date_based='Yes' and (NOW() between date_start and date_end ))) 
        and showhide='0' order by sort_order asc";
```

Comment: Ohh...just replacing curdate to NOW, worked like magic... A small change made huge difference for me.... thnx....

Comment: @DrJManish   .. curdate() return only the date part  and not the time ..